# Android Shortcuts works with minimumSdkVersion lower than 25?

Tags: android

Does Android shortcuts work with the apps which have minSdkVersion lower than 25 ?
Which compiledSdkVersion should be used to compile the project with shortcuts ?

According to [Android Developer website](https://developer.android.com), Launcher Shortcuts API is introduced in API 25.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts.html) was introduced with API 25.
To use them you have to use:

```
compileSdkVersion 25
```

or higher.

You can use a lower `minSdkVersion`, but of course it works only on Android 7.1 or higher and it's good practice to add the annotation `@TargetApi(25)` to the code to avoid compile errors and add a condition on the version before calling these methods.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 25) {
   // ShortcutManager...
}
```

Comment: what about minimumSdkVersion ? Thanks.